# Can I display the social login button alongside only the email field + continue button in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to show social buttons on page without the OrchestrationStep of type  `Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp"`.

On first screen I just want to show email field and continue button also with social buttons.

Here is my first step

```xml
<!-- First perform email discovery to determine if net new or existing-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-UsernameDiscovery" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

I just tried the `Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp"` but this shows both email + password on the page

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by chaining two `CombinedSignUpOrSignIn` orchestrations with the first only collecting email address.

Note; because the password field does not exist in the DOM, password managers will fail to autofill the email address.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchangeCollectionScreen" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchangeCollectionScreen" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchangeCollectionScreen" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-CollectEmailScreen" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>signInName</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchangeCollectionScreen" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchangeCollectionScreen" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <Preconditions>
    <!-- Skip if they have signed up in the first set of screens -->
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

The new technical profile I added was:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-CollectEmailScreen">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchangeCollectionScreen</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```